# Github desktop cannot commit with precommit hook

Tags: pre-commit-hook, github-desktop, pre-commit, husky

I am using win10.

when clicking the blue button on the Github desktop to commit something.

error `husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)` appears.

But if i type git commit -m "sth" in terminal, the pre-commit hook works fine

=============================

part of my package.json

```
 "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,tsx,ts}": "eslint --cache --fix",
    "*.{js,css,md,jsx,tsx,ts}": "prettier --write"
  }
```

============================

.husky/pre-commit.sh

```
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
```

============================

.husky/_/husky.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$husky_skip_init" ]; then
  debug () {
    if [ "$HUSKY_DEBUG" = "1" ]; then
      echo "husky (debug) - $1"
    fi
  }

  readonly hook_name="$(basename "$0")"
  debug "starting $hook_name..."

  if [ "$HUSKY" = "0" ]; then
    debug "HUSKY env variable is set to 0, skipping hook"
    exit 0
  fi

  if [ -f ~/.huskyrc ]; then
    debug "sourcing ~/.huskyrc"
    . ~/.huskyrc
  fi

  export readonly husky_skip_init=1
  sh -e "$0" "$@"
  exitCode="$?"

  if [ $exitCode != 0 ]; then
    echo "husky - $hook_name hook exited with code $exitCode (error)"
  fi

  exit $exitCode
fi
```

Comment: are you using gitbash terminal ?

Comment: Hi @Aron, any solutions? I have the same error

Answer (score 0):

The issue (even though it's not a real issue! ) is because of the hooks created by Husky. Husky is an npm package that lets you define npm scripts that correlate to local Git events such as a commit or push. And this helps in enforcing collaborative standards in a project. The quick solution, if you are too busy, is to simply delete the hooks folder for git which defines the pre-commit hooks and hence can push after that. (This is just kind of a hack to avoid editing thousands of files at a time for lint errors. Follow the guidelines and resolve all the lint errors for better code quality and maintainability. ) But it's always better to understand how Husky and hooks work and properly follow the lint warnings.

Edit: You can also skip hooks when you provide the git command line argument —no-verify,

> git push origin master --no-verify

, or use Sourcetree‘s Bypass commit hooks setting (in the menu to the top right of the commit message field)